# ARcore - How to get distance of one node from other Node?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am looking for the method to find the distance of one Node from other Node in ARCore sceneform SDK. I have looked into `overlapTestAll()` and `overlapTest()` which only returns a list node that are colliding with each other. I am assuming this method is returning list by calculation of distance between the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Get distance between vectors in meters:

```
private float getDistanceBetweenVectorsInMeters(Vector3 to, Vector3 from) 
{
    // Compute the difference vector between the two hit locations.
    float dx = to.x - from.x;
    float dy = to.y - from.y;
    float dz = to.z - from.z;

    // Compute the straight-line distance (distanceMeters)
    return (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [getWorldPosition()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/Node#getWorldPosition()) and then you can calculate the difference between the two x/y/z positions.